# Oracle APEX application be used to run scripts on the client side

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

Can an Oracle APEX application be used to run scripts on the client side local (w7) PC?
I would like to be able to communicate with devices on the local PC, collect data and post it back up to the database. This is for the purpose of test automation which was previously done using MS VBA and MS access.

Comment: Not really - at least not *just* APEX.  You'd probably need to integrate Java code to interact with the local PC.

Answer (score 3):

As with any other sort of web application, not easily.  For good reason, web browsers generally do not allow web applications to execute random executables on the client machine.  If they did, it would be a huge security hole that would allow an attacker to do whatever they want to your machine just because you visited a malicious web page.

Potentially, you could write (or find) an ActiveX control or a Java applet or some other sort of client-side control that could be given privileges to run scripts on the client machine.  But that would probably require a pretty substantial amount of "futzing" with permissions that might make the machine vulnerable to malicious web sites.

Assuming that there are a relatively small number of client machines, you could also potentially install the Oracle Scheduler Agent on each of the machines that you want to execute scripts on and then use the Oracle Scheduler on the database to start jobs on the remote machines.  If you did this, you could potentially start jobs on any of the client machines from an APEX interface.

Comment: This is for an internal project of fairly small size. Currently implemented in MS Access. The server itself could be on the client PC, however that is not the most desirable configuration.

Comment: I should add that MS access is linked to another SQL database.